Azure automation error on azure.storage.blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings

ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'

In azure automation I deployed my code and test pane it/run the code faced the errors
In requirements I am using azure-storage-blob==12.20.0
I am using in azure automation editor and my python code in (python version 3.8)
still I am facing the above error


In order to use azure.storage.blob in Azure automation, you need to add azure-storage-blob and azure-core packages to it.
Download the .whl files for both the packages by navigating to pypi.org site as shown below.



Then import it by navigation to Python Packages blade in your Automation account.




By performing the above steps, I am able to execute the given code.

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="{connectionString}", container_name="sample-container")

blob_list = container.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print(blob.name + '\n')

print("Test Completed..")




While adding a python package pydantic_core , pyodbc it is keep on geTting failed
I tried latest pydantic_core and this version both are failingpydantic_core-2.18.4-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64
similarly for pyodbc

Try to use Runtime version as 3.10 while adding the packages. I am able to import it https://i.imgur.com/BL6gmM4.png

Thank you it worked with 3.10 But there is one more package i am getting failed i am using windows below have the details  Tried latest version and also 3.7.4.post0
Failed
The job failed because it could not install aiohttp python package imported in automation account. Error: Unexpected file structure in .whl file for python package aiohttp. It is likely that the package is for an unsupported platform. Supported platform tags are - manylinux_2_17_x86_64 and manylinux2014_x86_64.

try to add the packages correctly before use and try on different runtimes 3.8 or 3.10

In 3.8 version Packages pyodbc , pydantic_core is getting failed for 3.10 it is working well so if I use 3.8 version and packages also I opt python 3.8 for packages not supported in python 3.8 can i select python 3.10...??
